# Objective-C: Will method swizzling affect the objects created before swizzling?

Tags: objective-c

I'm swizzling a method of `UIDevice`, which is created before my swizzling code, will it still be working? And Why?

My understanding is that swizzling is like changing the path that method is dispatched, so once you swizzle it, all the calls after will be affected, is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: existing objects will be affected by swizzling as the whole class is affected. The Objective-C method dispatching can't have one "path" for one object and another one for another object *of the same class*. There's a kind of lookup table for each class that determines which code to execute for a selector (method).

Simple test program to verify:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface Dummy : NSObject

- (void)printSomething;
+ (void)swizzle;

@end


@implementation Dummy

- (void)printSomething
{
    NSLog(@"Foo");
}

- (void)swizzledPrintSomething
{
    NSLog(@"Bar");
}

+ (void)swizzle
{
    Method original, swizzled;

    original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(printSomething));
    swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzledPrintSomething));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}


Dummy * dummy = [[Dummy alloc] init];
[dummy printSomething]; // Prints: Foo
[Dummy swizzle];
[dummy printSomething]; // Prints: Bar
```